# Best way to redirect to www in Rails while handling localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On my Rails 6 site, I want to make sure the user is always on the www subdomain - e.g. [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and **not** on example.com or foo.example.com

**However** I also need to handle localhost, and various IP addresses, when developing locally.

I started with this relatively elegant approach:

```
if request.subdomain != 'www'
  redirect_to url_for(subdomain: 'www', only_path: false)
end
```

Of course, that would redirect localhost too, so then I added a check. But then it choked on ip addresses. Now my application controller looks like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_action :ensure_www
  
  # Other stuff

  def ensure_www
    unless request.domain.nil?
      unless request.domain.include? 'localhost'
        if request.subdomain != 'www'
          redirect_to url_for(subdomain: 'www', only_path: false)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now it doesn't look so elegant any more. Is there a best practice way of handling this in Rails?

(Note: I moved the ensure_www method into a concern already.)

Answer (score 0):

You may cut this code and past to your ApplicationconController_helper, include it as a model inside ApplicationController. I thought an elegant way to handle this is the same as turn the others rails developer's life easy to read your application. By convention, every thing that over pass the main aim of a controller must be written on a helper.

Comment: Paulo, actually I put it in a concern. I was only writing it that way for the purpose of keeping my code example brief. What I'm bothered about is the two nested `unless` conditionals. I figured this must be a common pattern that people have a standard solution for. (I'll add a note to make it clear that it is already in a concern.)